# How to contribute by PR to multiple forks from a single base

Tags: git, github

Assume A is a rather snazzy and widely used piece of software with a repo on GitHub and multiple forks. Call them B, C, D.

I wish to submit changes to any or all of them (A,B,C,D).

GitHub does not allow a 'fork of a fork', so if I fork any one of them I can't easily submit PRs to the others.

Obviously I can clone them all locally and do the work locally. I can even create an upstream origin for each of them on GitHub, but not a fork.

So the time comes to submit a PR to B. I can create a (temporary) fork of B, and create and submit a PR. In due course I can delete the fork.

But I now have some other changes to submit to C, and I'm stuck. I cannot delete the fork of B because the PR is outstanding, so I cannot submit the PR on C. Show stopper.

Is there a solution to this conundrum, and if so what is it?

Comment: Why would you not be able to submit a PR on C if B has an open PR?

Comment: Because you can't fork C until you kill B, and that kills the PR on B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can never be the case that:

1. You cannot create a fork from which to submit a PR; and
2. You do not already have a suitable fork.

Your issue is that you don't think your existing fork is suitable, but it is. Whatever the work is that you have locally which you want to share, you can just push that up as a (potentially, new) branch to your existing fork, and PR from there.

Comment: It worked. Like a bought one.